# How to clear the button color when i click next button?

Tags: android, button

```
       public class TrueFalseActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{
        Button buttonClicked = null;
        List<QuestionTrueFalse> questionTrueFalseList;
        int myscore = 0;
        int quid=0;
        int id ;
        TextView tv, tv1;
       QuestionTrueFalse curQues;
        Button b1, b2;
        Button next, back;
         Button button;

        QuestionTrueFalse cur;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_trfal);
            tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
            b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
            b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);

            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
            b2.setOnClickListener(this);
            DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);

            questionTrueFalseList = db.getAllTrFalsQuestions();
            if (questionTrueFalseList != null && questionTrueFalseList.size() != 0) {
                curQues = questionTrueFalseList.get(quid);
                try {
                    setQuestionView();
                }catch (NullPointerException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception caught",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
     next=(Button) findViewById(R.id.forw);
            back=(Button) findViewById(R.id.back);
            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   button=(Button) v;

                   String buttonText=button.getText().toString();



                    if(curQues.getAnsw().equals(buttonText))
                    {
                        myscore++;
                    }
                    cur=curQues;

                    if(quid<19){
                        quid++;
                        curQues=questionTrueFalseList.get(quid);


                        setQuestionView();

                    }else{

                        Intent intent = new Intent(TrueFalseActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        b.putInt("score", myscore); //Your score
                        intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
     back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (quid > 0) {
                        quid--;
                        curQues = questionTrueFalseList.get(quid);
                        setQuestionView();
                    }
                }
            });
    private void setQuestionView() {
            tv.setText(curQues.getQues());
            b1.setText(curQues.getOpt1());
            b2.setText(curQues.getOpt2());
                }
     public void onClick(View v) {
           // final Button button;

            button=(Button) v;
                 String buttonText=button.getText().toString();
    enter code here
//Button is set red if answer is correct..
            if (curQues.getAnsw().equals(buttonText))
            {
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

                  myscore++;


            }
     //Button will be set to red if answer is false
            else
            {
                button.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

            }
             if(quid>19){
                        countDownTimer.cancel();
                        timerHasStarted = false;
                Intent intent = new Intent(TrueFalseActivity.this, ResultActivity.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putInt("score", myscore); //Your score
                intent.putExtras(b); //Put your score to your next Intent
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
    }
    }
```

Am developing quiz app which has 2 buttons with one onClick(). I clicked on one button and clicked next same color is being carried to next button how 
    to clear the button color when i click next button.
    How should I clear the colour which is carried on to next question? I am new to android. Can any one help me out to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the color of the button while clicking the next button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `onClickListener` for your next button you need to reset the color of your buttons;

like this:

```
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) { 
        b1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
        b2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working same colour is being carried to next question.

Comment: where did you used this line?

Comment: next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               button=(Button) v;

               String buttonText=button.getText().toString();
                button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);

Comment: Inside next button I used this line

Comment: ok. in that scope `button` represent  your `next` button and not the one you colored. so you need to use this method with `b1` and `b2` like: `b1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);` and `b2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);`

Comment: next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               button=(Button) v;

               String buttonText=button.getText().toString();
                button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);

Comment: No as I already told you in my previous comment inside your next button `button` represents `next` button itself. so you need not to use `button` there and have to use `b1` and `b2` like this : `b1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);` `b2.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);` check updated answer

Comment: k.thank you,its working but when I click next button both true and false buttons should be set to default colour(it means button colour should be cleared and set to default colour when I click on next..)Please help me.